# Making a time counter while waiting for user input in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a "tamagoshi" like game to practice ruby. I want the program to wait for user input to do something, but from time to time (right now I am using 10 seconds until I get it right) I want a method to occur (the pet looses energy, and becomes sadder with time). But if the user inputs an action, I want the timer to stop e reset.

I'm having some problems, tried different things and right now, I am only able to do one action. After that, nothing happens. I guess I'm not creating a new thread after doing ".join" but I'm not sure.

I very much welcome all critics on the rest of the code to improve my skills and knowledge as I just started learning ruby.

```
dog = Dog.new 'Yoshi'

def play pet
  user_action = nil

  timer_thread = Thread.new do
    while !user_action
      (1..10).each do |number|
        sleep(1)
        puts number
      end
      pet.time_goes_on
      user_action = nil
    end
  end

  user_action = gets.chomp

  case user_action
  when "play"
    pet.play_fetch

  when "eat"
    pet.feed
  when "train"
    pet.training
  when "sleep"
    pet.sleep
  when "walk"
    pet.take_for_a_walk
  else
    puts "invalid command, try again"
    play(pet)
  end
  timer_thread.join
end

while dog.is_alive
  play(dog)
end
```

Here's the full code at repl.it:
[tama'yoshi'](https://repl.it/E9Yo/0)

Comment: Please put the code in the question. External links require additional work to open, some people are leery of clicking arbitrary off-site links, and the content there might expire.

Comment: ok. I did't want to post such a big block of code here, so if someone wants to see the Dog object, just click the link where I saved the project at repl.it

Comment: It's best to post a minimal amount of code that demonstrates your problem and allows others to reproduce it. What you have here is almost too much but is fine. What you really need is an event loop where you can spin while waiting for user input. That's the fundamental core of most games.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand completely. What you need is that if the user does not run an action before 10 seconds, the pet lose energy for example, but if press eat, the time it's going to reset. That is right?

Comment: Exactly Andrés! After 10 seconds I want to call the Dog object method that makes the dog loses energy and his happiness level. If you call one of the possible methods to do something with the dog (with one of the words on the switch/case), the time needs to reset, and again waits for a new user input. I can't seem to figure out the right loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a solution!

```
dog = Dog.new 'Yoshi'

def play pet
  while pet.is_alive

    user_action = nil

    timer_thread = Thread.new do
      while user_action == nil
        (1..10).each do |number|
          sleep(1)
          number
          if number == 10
            pet.time_goes_on
          end
          break if (user_action != nil)
        end
      end
    end

    user_action = gets.chomp

    case user_action
    when "play"
      pet.play_fetch
    when "eat"
      pet.feed
    when "train"
      pet.training
    when "sleep"
      pet.sleep
    when "walk"
      pet.take_for_a_walk
    else
      puts "invalid command, try again"
      play(pet)
    end
    timer_thread.join
  end
end

play(dog)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Can you add your full code with the Dog class definition please? :)

Comment: Sorry, this was an old project that I no longer have and don't really remember tbh. For what I remember you could access to it by clicking the link.